# get the arithmetic average using shell

Tags: shell, awk

The following is the output of ping 2 urls.

```
PING www.abc.com (96.126.98.69): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 96.126.98.69: icmp_seq=0 ttl=43 time=444.812 ms
64 bytes from 96.126.98.69: icmp_seq=1 ttl=43 time=467.554 ms

--- www.abc.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 444.812/456.183/467.554/11.371 ms
PING www.kkk.com (90.187.36.10): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 90.187.36.10: icmp_seq=0 ttl=51 time=404.907 ms
64 bytes from 90.187.36.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=427.510 ms

--- www.kkk.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 404.907/416.208/427.510/11.302 ms
```

I want to get the arithmetic value of time for each ip. like

```
96.126.98.69 a_time = 456.183
90.187.36.10 a_time = 416.208
```

I just can get each ip with time using following code:

```
cat out | grep "64 bytes"
```

but I don't know how to get the arithmetic average for each ip.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
num=2
cat ips |
xargs -n1 ping -c $num |
awk -vnum=$num -F'[ =:]' '
    /^[0-9]+ bytes +from/{
        ips[$4]+=$11
    }
    END{
        for (ip in ips) print ip, "a_time =", ips[ip]/num
    }
'
```

### Example of output

```
127.0.0.1 a_time = 0.0225
8.8.8.8 a_time = 25.7
```

### Explanation

- I use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to add the milliseconds into an array with the ip as a key
- @the end, I iterate through the array and divide by the num variable integer (2 here)
- I split columns with spaces,  `=` and `:` with `-F` switch

Answer (score 0):

How about an `awk` one liner:

```
awk -F'[:= ]' '/^64 b/{a[$4]+=$11}END{for(k in a)print k,"a_time =",a[k]/2}' out
90.187.36.10 a_time = 416.208
96.126.98.69 a_time = 456.183
```

If you increase the number of packets from `ping -c 2` to say `ping -c 5` then change the last `a[k]/2` to `a[k]/5` optionally you can use the `awk` option `-v` to pass in the value as a variable.

Comment: So, you will re-write all my answer ?

Comment: Maybe the OP wants a concise solution.

Comment: `-c` don't increase packets but the number of tries.

Comment: [man ping](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping) `-c count - Stop after sending count ECHO_REQUEST packets`